# arecord to record what is playing on speakers

Tags: audio

The command `arecord foo.wav` records from microphone and saves to file foo.wav.

Is there a way I can have arecord record what is coming out of speakers instead of recording from microphone? Or perhaps there are other command line tools that can do this?

I would rather avoid bloaty graphical tools like Audacity.

I am on Arch if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1):

The [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#ALSA_monitor_source) tells you how to setup an ALSA source as a monitor.

Basically, use `pactl list` to find the name of your source, something that includes `analog-stereo.monitor`. Then add to `/etc/asound.conf` or `~/.asoundrc` the following lines:

```
pcm.pulse_monitor {
  type pulse
  device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
}

ctl.pulse_monitor {
  type pulse
  device alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor
}
```

Then select that source for recording. The `arecord` manual lists some options for specifying a device to use if it doesn't automatically use the right one.

```
-l, --list-devices
    List all soundcards and digital audio devices 
-L, --list-pcms
    List all PCMs defined 
-D, --device=NAME
    Select PCM by name
```